# Move custom event handler from View to ViewModel

Tags: wpf, events

I have a custom event named OnVisualChartRangeChanged being fired from a UserControl called HistoricChartControl.

I am using the control in my main application like this:

```
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:HistoricViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>


<Grid>
    <historicChart:HistoricChartControl >
        <historicChart:HistoricChartControl 
            behaviours:ChartBehavior.OnVisualChartRangeChanged="VisualChartRangeChanged"/>
        </historicChart:HistoricChartControl>
</Grid>
```

I want that instead of having the event being handled in the view via the method VisualChartRangeChanged, the event be handled in the ViewModel.

How could I modify my code for this to happen? It would be helpful if you could post specific code as I am new to the WPF way of doing things.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, what does the event handler do? Does it do Data-related stuff? then it belongs into the ViewModel (or the Model, depending on Dependencies and such). Does it do UI-related stuff? then it's ok to keep it in code behind. Does it perform business logic? then it belongs into the ViewModel or the Model as well.

Comment: It uses the new scroll DateTime min/max range to do a linq query through a database in the Viewmodel. The return from this query will then be used to set a new Y-axis min/max range on the UI. This is why I need the event handled in the Viewmodel; the buisness logic needs to see the parameters passed by the handler so that it can perform the query. Can you advise?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use Commands.

Since its a UserControl you may manipulate it to implement ICommandSource interface.

Then your UserControl will be able to bind a Command to ViewModel.

Once the event is being fired you simply call the command which will invoke Execute() method from the ViewModel.

For commanding in WPF I suggest you to read following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308(v=vs.110).aspx

In your ViewModel you will have to offer a property of type ICommand.

**EDIT** Since you cannot manipulate your UserControl you will have to attach a command on it in XAML.

Interactivity is also an alternative to solve your issue. Take a look at this code:

```
 xmlns:I="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

<ListBox ...>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedItemChangedCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

Interactivity is a third party dll from Microsoft Blend.

If you have nuget in visual studio you will be able to find that dll. If not here is the link: http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/

Comment: Hi, I do not have access to the UserControl's code. Can I do this without it?

Answer (score 0):

***This answer is changed once.***

### Interactivity Solution:

If the used behavior is reusable (you have its source) you can simply move the logic of this behavior to ViewModel level. Follow these 4 steps and it should work if the bindings and DataContext values are correct.

- Add reference of both `System.Windows.Interactivity` and `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` to your project:

---

- Create a Command in ViewModel

  ```
  //ViewModel:
      public ICommand VisualChartRangeChangedCommand
      {
          get { return (ICommand)GetValue(VisualChartRangeChangedCommandProperty); }
          set { SetValue(VisualChartRangeChangedCommandProperty, value); }
      }
      public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualChartRangeChangedCommandProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("VisualChartRangeChangedCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


  //In ViewModel constructor:
  VisualChartRangeChangedCommand = new ActionCommand(() => doStuff());
  ```

---

- override the Behavior and add command ability to it

  ```
  public class OnVisualChartRangeChangedWithCommand : OnVisualChartRangeChanged<HistoricChartControl>
  {
      //MyCommand Dependency Property
      public ICommand MyCommand
      {
          get { return (ICommand)GetValue(MyCommandProperty); }
          set { SetValue(MyCommandProperty, value); }
      }
      public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCommandProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("MyCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(OnVisualChartRangeChangedWithCommand), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

      protected override void OnAttached()
      {
          //replace MouseEnter with other events related to OnVisualChartRangeChanged
          AssociatedObject.MouseEnter += _eh;
          base.OnAttached();
      }
      protected override void OnDetaching()
      {
          AssociatedObject.MouseEnter -= _eh;
          base.OnDetaching();
      }
      void _eh(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      {
          if (MyCommand != null)
              MyCommand.Execute(null);
      }
  }
  ```

---

- Link the ViewModel's `Command` to the overriden `Behavior`

  ```
  xmlns:I="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
  xmlns:B="clr-namespace:CoreProject.Behaviors;assembly=CoreProject"

  <historicChart:HistoricChartControl>
      <I:Interaction.Behaviors>
          <B:OnVisualChartRangeChangedWithCommand MyCommand="{Binding VisualChartRangeChangedCommand}"/>
      </I:Interaction.Behaviors>
  </historicChart:HistoricChartControl>
  ```

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately, the UserControl is not mine, and I do not have access to the behaviour class. i am unable to modify it. Is there another way?